# >> Error: Cannot find module 'load-grunt-config' how can I get grunt to work?

Tags: gruntjs

I've cloned a repo that I'm supposed to be working on.

I then tried running the following commands:

- `npm install`
- `bower install`
- As well as: `cd` to my folder and `npm install grunt --save-dev`

However, when I run `grunt` I get the following error:

> `Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR`
>
> `>> Error: Cannot find module 'load-grunt-config'`
>
> `Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.`
>
> `Aborted due to warnings.`
>
> `Execution Time (2018-05-07 11:23:14 UTC+10)`
>
> `loading tasks  6ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 86%`
>
> `Total 7ms`

This is my `Gruntfile.js`:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
    jitGrunt: true
  });

};
```

How can I fix this? I am really stuck.

Comment: Can you add the content of your `package.json` file to the question?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you don't have 'load-grunt-config' installed (at least I get the exact same error by removing the folder from my node_modules).

run `npm install load-grunt-config` and/or fix your package.json file by adding `"load-grunt-config": "^0.19.2"`to the related dependencies.